# How to create a "formula checker" in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find a way to check if (thousands of) formulas are correct.

Here is a sample of such a formula:

```
(Z9-Z200-Z201)*(Z1427<2)+(Z20*(Z1428>0)+Z21*(Z1429>0)+Z22*(Z1430>0)+Z23*(Z1431>0))*(Z1427=2)+(Z250*(Z1428>1)+Z250*(Z1453=1))*(Z1427=2)+(Z4253+Z4250)*(Z4249=1)
```

The "Z" is nothing else than a kind of wildcard (all of them start with "Z" followed by a 1-4 digit number)
These formulas can also contain double and integer numbers, operators like "+-/*" and some keywords like "TAN()", "SIN()" or "COS()".

There is no limitation regarding nested brackets but I guess there should be max. 4 or 5 levels of nesting.

Does anyone know how to do this - my preferred environment is VB.net

Thanks
Markus

Comment: The full answer would be too long for this site. Are you stuck on *specific* problems?

Comment: The most general answer would involve writing a full expression parser.  If there are specific problems that you're looking for, it might be more tractable as a more specialized check e.g. a paren matching checker (ultimately a test of whether the count of `(` matches the count of `)`) or a regular expression to look for a specific known issue.

Comment: I am not sure how to start with a full expression parser ... my poor idea would be to check if there are two operators in a sequence like "/*" or "+*" or other stuff like "(*"

I am very sure that this covers only a minor part of all possible common errors within all the formulas ...

Comment: Those would fit in with "more specialized check" that I mentioned before.  There isn't necessarily anything special to do, the ones that you mention might all be done by iterating over the string, remembering the previous character, and checking if you have two incompatible characters in sequence.  There shouldn't be anything especially technically challenging about it.